# ImageMagick pango vertical alignment

Tags: imagemagick

It's been 3 or 4 hours I've been searching for it.

This is my command:

```
convert -gravity center -size 500x500 -background '#263238' -fill white -font "IRANSans.ttf" -pointsize 32 pango:"<span face='IRANSans' foreground='white'>درود</span>" bge.png
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwVr4.png)

But I want to put this text in the middle of the picture. Same thing that this line does in CSS:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Have you tried `label:` instead of `pango:` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by [Marek Rost](https://superuser.com/questions/1106867/imagemagick-pango-vertical-alignment#comment1574861_1106867):

```
convert -background '#263238' -fill white -font "IRAN-sans-Regular" \
    -size 500x500  -pointsize 32  -gravity center label:"دورد" bge.png
```

I reversed the characters. You can list the fonts with `convert -list font`.

Or with Pango

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:'#263238' \
    \( -gravity Center -size 100x50 -background none \
    -font "IRANSans.ttf" -pointsize 32 \
    pango:"<span face='IRANSans' foreground='white'>درود</span>" \) \
    -gravity Center -composite bge.png
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted :) I used another method that used about 3 commands, but this is only one command. That's great!